# MySQL with CASE WHEN ELSE to filter product IDs based on value in another column and a subquery?

Tags: mysql, group-concat

Ok, I'm lost... I just spent 3 hours looking at this and tweaking it, twisting it, rewriting it, rearranging it and I can't figure it out.

What I have is multiple tables that I am joining to get the relevant information I need, obviously... so something like this (very simplified):

```
 job_id | part_id | part_title | override | override_id
 1      | 5       | part1      | 1        | 7
 1      | 6       | part2      | 1        | 7
 1      | 7       | part3_kit  | 1        | NULL
 1      | 8       | part4      | 1        | 9
 1      | 9       | part5_kit  | 1        | NULL
 1      | 10      | part6      | 1        | NULL
 1      | 11      | part7      | 1        | 15
```

the premise is simple - there is a collection of parts and part kits, where part kits contain specific parts (think of group of parts).

If "override" field is turned on (= 1) then I want to show only those parts that 1) do not have "override_id" (override_id IS NULL) AND 2) other parts have "part_id" for these parts referenced in their "override_id" column, AND 3) might have a value in "override_id" column but that referenced "part_id" is not within the given results and as such they cannot be replaced and need to be included as well.

Vice versa, if "override" is turned off (= 0), then I want to show all the parts that are not kits (kits = other parts have them referenced in "override_id" column).

So, for example, if override = 1, then what should be listed would be part_ids 7, 9 10, 11 (7 and 9 are referenced as kits in "override_id" column, 10 is just a single part with no override reference/not a kit and 11 is a single part with a reference to override part, but that part is not in the existing list of results so the single part is not being replace by the kit and is being included instead).

If override = 0, then what should be listed would be part_ids 5, 6, 9, 10, 11 (as again, 7 and 9 are referenced as kits in "override_id" column for these specific results, and as such those should be omitted, while 11 should be included as its override part id 15 is not included in the results and as such part 11 cannot be replaced with an override part - it needs to be included as well).

NOTE: "override" field is pulled from another, external table (a global setting that's either 0 or 1, never a mix of both) via a JOIN but for the sake of argument and simplicity I'm including it here as part of this single table.

Here is the query I've been trying to put together, but I'm running into roadblocks everywhere:

```
SELECT
j.job_id,
pt.part_id,
pt.part_title,
pt.override,
pt.override_id,
(SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT pt.override_id)
    FROM job j
    INNER JOIN part_type pt ON j.part_id = pt.part_id
    WHERE j.job_id = 1
    AND pt.override_id IS NOT NULL) AS override_ids
FROM job j
INNER JOIN part_type pt ON j.part_id = pt.part_id
WHERE j.job_id = 1
AND pt.part_id NOT IN (
    CASE pt.override 
    WHEN '1' THEN IF(pt.override_id IS NOT NULL, pt.part_id, NULL)
    WHEN '0' THEN override_ids
    END)
GROUP BY j.job_id, pt.part_title
ORDER BY pt.part_title;
```

For the query above I get error saying:

> Error in query (1054): Unknown column 'override_ids' in 'where clause'

If I move that SELECT subquery from the top to my CASE WHEN part:

```
SELECT
j.job_id,
pt.part_id,
pt.part_title,
pt.override,
pt.override_id
FROM job j
INNER JOIN part_type pt ON j.part_id = pt.part_id
WHERE j.job_id = 1
AND pt.part_id NOT IN (
    CASE pt.override 
    WHEN '1' THEN IF(pt.override_id IS NOT NULL, pt.part_id, NULL)
    WHEN '0' THEN (SELECT
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT pt.override_id)
        FROM job j
        INNER JOIN part_type pt ON j.part_id = pt.part_id
        WHERE j.job_id = 1
        AND pt.override_id IS NOT NULL)
    END)
GROUP BY j.job_id, pt.part_title
ORDER BY pt.part_title;
```

That GROUP_CONCAT returns a string instead of a list of integers, so plugged in back into the parent NOT IN (...) it only evaluates for the first value, not all of them. In this case, it will return 7,9 but only 7 will evaluate in NOT IN (...) part.

Now, if I remove the GROUP_CONCAT from the subquery and just leave it as SELECT DISTINCT pt.override_id FROM... I get this as an error message:

> Error in query (1242): Subquery returns more than 1 row

So I'm just lost here... out of ideas.

Help, anyone?

I wish I had more experience with MySQL to see my way out of this, but I've tried everything in my power and on my level of knowledge so far, and 3 hours later I'm close to the end goal, but not really.

What am I missing?

And if you see that this query can be optimized or simplified even further, feel free to comment, as again, I'm still learning and I'm probably missing something obvious to you experts...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: sqlfillde: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f09c30/1

Comment: Create 2 subqeries for the 2 cases something like `SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(part_id),override,override_id FROM whatver WHERE override=1 AND...` same for the other case with  override=0  and then JOIN these 2 GROUP_CONCAT results with FIND_IN_SET on the main query.

Comment: ? But overide is never 0 ?!?!

Comment: Override is pulled from another table, and it's sometimes 0, sometimes 1, depending on the record. So assume it's either 0 OR 1 for any specific query, never a mix of the two (it's a global switch the user can turn on or off)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have 3 groups of parts:

- parts that are referenced by another part, called kit (#references to it > 0)
- parts that are part of a kit (-> override_id <> null)
- parts that are not referenced by another part, and are not part of a kit (->override_id is null and #references to it = 0)

So do a (sub)query that just calculate these values:

```
select
    pt.part_id,
    pt.part_title,
    (select count(*) 
     from part_type pt1
     where pt1.override_id = pt.part_id) as cntrefs,
    pt.override_id 
from part_type pt
```

this will give you:

```
    part_id | part_title | cntrefs  | override_id
    5       | part1      | 0        | 7
    6       | part2      | 0        | 7
    7       | part3_kit  | 2        | NULL
    8       | part4      | 0        | 9
    9       | part5_kit  | 1        | NULL
    10      | part6      | 0        | NULL
```

Depending on where you get pr.override from (I assume you join a pr-table somewhere outside) you can now filter from this selection the two cases:

```
select ... from ( <insert the above> ) as parts
join job j on j.part_id = parts.part_id
<insert pr.override from somewhere, something like "join options as pr">
where j.job_id = 1 and 
   ( ( pr.override = 1 and (parts.override_id is null))
   or ( pr.override = 0 and (parts.cntrefs > 0)) )
-- maybe you need a group here, depending on your "job"-table     
-- group by j.job_id, pt.part_id, ...
```

Where you put your where-statements and if you should put it directly inside the query depends on your data and that override-flag, but you should get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after an extra hour of fiddling with it and moving things around, I've managed to cover all the conditions AND get the query to evaluate properly.

Here is what I've got as the final query, but feel free to suggest more optimal solutions (thanks for the FIND_IN_SET suggestion, totally forgot about that one, as that would take GROUP_CONCAT string value and evaluate it fully unlike NOT IN).

```
SELECT
j.job_id,
pt.part_id,
pt.part_title,
pt.override,
pt.override_id
FROM job j
INNER JOIN part_type pt ON j.part_id = pt.part_id
WHERE j.job_id = 1
AND
    CASE pt.override 
        WHEN '1' THEN IF(pt.override_id IS NULL, 
                         pt.override_id IS NULL, 
                         NOT FIND_IN_SET(pt.override_id,
        (SELECT
            GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT pt.part_id)
            FROM job j
            INNER JOIN part_type pt ON j.part_id = pt.part_id
            WHERE j.job_id = 1
        ))) 
        WHEN '0' THEN NOT FIND_IN_SET(pt.part_id, 
        (SELECT
            GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT pt.override_id)
            FROM job j
            INNER JOIN part_type pt ON j.part_id = pt.part_id
            WHERE j.job_id = 1
            AND pt.override_id IS NOT NULL))
    END
GROUP BY j.job_id, pt.part_title
ORDER BY pt.part_title;
```

I just didn't know that CASE WHEN could be applied in WHERE / AND conditions too... very handy!